# Clever way of building a tag cloud? - Python

Tags: python, django, indexing, keyword, data-mining

I've built a content aggregator and would like to add a tag cloud representing the current trends.

Unfortunately this is quite complex, as I have to look for **keywords** that represent the context of each article.

For example words such as **I**, **was**, **the**, **amazing**, **nice** have no relation to context.

---

Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [NLTK](http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds13-4/natural_language.html), and in particular its **Stopwords corpus**:

> Besides regular content words, there
>   is another class of words called stop
>   words that perform important
>   grammatical functions, but are
>   unlikely to be interesting by
>   themselves. These include
>   prepositions, complementizers, and
>   determiners. NLTK comes bundled with
>   the Stopwords corpus, a list of 2400
>   stop words across 11 different
>   languages (including English).

Comment: @Alex: thanks for the awesome answer! But can this deal with adjectives such as **good** **great** etc... ?

Comment: @Radiant, adjectives aren't stopwords, as they do convey meaning -- e.g., "The Great Wall" is a very specific and long wall in China, while "The Wall" is a Pink Floyd album -- etc.  If you want to skip adjectives (a dubious decision), use NLTK to do "Parts-of-Speech tagging", per http://streamhacker.com/2008/11/03/part-of-speech-tagging-with-nltk-part-1/ (also read parts 2 and 3 of course).

Answer (score 2):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) can help you analyze the content in order to pick out relevant terms.